# get sibling div of element just clicked and insert into div jquery is returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, featherlight.js

I am using featherlight.js to create modal pop ups when some links are clicked. I have several of the same-class links, in a series of divs, that each pop up into a modal showing different pictures and captions. The pictures are popping up in the modal correctly. I am trying to add some jquery to: retrieve and find the previous sibling div of the anchor element just clicked, and insert that div's html div into a div in the modal pop up (image caption). this is what I have for jquery:

```
    "<div class='modal-caption'>" + jQuery("#modalTrigger").click(function(){
var caption = jQuery(this).prev("div");
var partcap = caption.html();
return partcap; })

,"</div>"
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="timeline-box-inner animate-right animated">
<span class="arrow"></span>
<div class="date">1974 - 1976</div>
    <h3>High School</h3>
    <h4>
    <a href="http://whs.westside66.org/">
    Westside</a>
    </h4>

    <div id="mdc" class="display-none-caption">Just A Test</div>
    <a id="modalTrigger" class="education-modal-link" href="http://johnhoich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/logo-compass-1.png" data-featherlight="image"></a>
```

I want to get the html (content) of id="mdc" inside this particular div and prepend/return/insert that content into div with class="modal-caption". I need to find the div within this particular parent because I have several div's with the class="timeline-box-inner" where the captions need to be pulled and added as a caption in the modal.

FYI this isn't working for me, it is returning as: [object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fragment should do what you want.

```js
$('.education-modal-link').on('click', function(e) {
  // prevent the default <a href> click behaviour
  e.preventDefault();
  // get the text from the sibling <div>
  var text = $(this).prev('div').text();
  // find the first div with a 'modal-caption' class
  // and add the text
  $('div.modal-caption').eq(0).html(text); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">1974 - 1976</div>
<h3>High School</h3>
<h4><a href="http://blah.org/">Westside</a></h4>
<div class="display-none-caption">Just A Test 1</div>
<a class="education-modal-link" href="http://johnhoich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/logo-compass-1.png" data-featherlight="image">click me</a>
<div class="display-none-caption">Just A Test 2</div>
<a class="education-modal-link" href="http://johnhoich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/logo-compass-1.png" data-featherlight="image">click me</a>
<div class="display-none-caption">Just A Test 3</div>
<a class="education-modal-link" href="http://johnhoich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/logo-compass-1.png" data-featherlight="image">click me</a>
<div class='modal-caption'>I'm going to change!</div>
```

Comment: I'm closer - but no dice! This didn't work when I clicked it the first time, but if i click it again, it works. I have to repeat this action several times on the same page - I have several links that should pop up different captions for each modal pop up - to my point, only the first link works (if i click it twice). and all the other links don't work

Comment: The event handler needs to be attached to the 'education-modal-link' class and not the id. I've updated the code fragment to demonstrate.

Comment: holy moly - duh! thank you - but ONE THING: it doesn't work on the first click. After I click one of the links once, then all of them start working. Why is this?

Comment: ...in other words - it fires after the first click

Comment: Are there other event handlers on the page?

Comment: just checked - there are event handlers for google maps

Comment: Can you add the link to the page here?

Comment: http://johnhoich.com/homepage/    scroll down to education section and click on the content cards to see in action

Comment: Looking at Chrome Dev Tools, the event handler isn't being attached until after the first time one of the elements is clicked. This would suggest there is an issue with where you placed the code to attach the event handler. Try placing it in the same section of the JavaScript file as other even handlers for the page.

Comment: This is how I have it attached: <a id="modalTrigger" class="education-modal-link" href="<?php echo esc_url($education['lightbox']);?>" data-featherlight="image"></a> and that is in a page template file. Is this what you're referring to...? @Dan

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in the `<head></head>`.

`<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       $("#modalTrigger").click(function(){
       $(".modal-caption").html($(this).prev("#mdc").html());
       });
    });
 </script>`